# HTML injection in Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, web, inject

I have to transform this code in order to use it for html injection in an Angular app (in this way it doesn't load any css or animations).

```
dataService.getThings().subscribe(
(data) => {
  const list = document.getElementById("nav-list");
  data.forEach((element: any) => {

    let actions = ``;
    Object.entries(element.actions).forEach((action: any) => {
      actions += `<button mat-button>${action[0]}</button>`;
    });

    let properties = ``;
    Object.entries(element.properties).forEach((property: any) => {
      properties += `<button mat-button>${property[0]}</button>`;
    });

    let thingExp = `<mat-expansion-panel>
                      <mat-expansion-panel-header>
                        ${element.title}
                      </mat-expansion-panel-header>
                      <ng-template matExpansionPanelContent>
                        ${actions}${properties}
                      </ng-template>
                    </mat-expansion-panel>`

    list!.innerHTML += thingExp;
  });
}
```

How can i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying to sanitize my html, the best solution, as suggested by Volkan Talayhan in the comments was to use Angular Dynamic Components.

This is the html part for the component:

```
<mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let element of data" class="panel" [attr.id]="element.id">
<mat-expansion-panel-header>
    {{ element.title }}
</mat-expansion-panel-header>
<ng-template matExpansionPanelContent class="btn-container">
    <button mat-button class="thing-btn" (click)="onAddThingNode(element.title, element.id)">{{ element.title }}</button>
    <button mat-button *ngFor="let action of getObjectKeys(element.actions)" class="action-btn"
        (click)="onAddActionNode(action, element.id)">{{ action }}</button>
    <button mat-button *ngFor="let property of getObjectKeys(element.properties)" class="property-btn"
        (click)="onAddPropertyNode(property, element.id)">{{ property }}</button>
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 0):

- Add a new pipe file into your project "SafeHtml.pipe.ts"
- Add "SafeHtml.pipe.ts to declarations in your app.module
- define a new string variable in your component.ts file first (forexample htmlContent='';)
- Replace list.innerHTML += thingExp; with this.htmlContent+=thingExp;
- in your component.html use <div [innerHtml]="htmlContent | safeHtml">

  ```
   //SafeHtml.pipe.ts
   import { Pipe ,PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';
   import {DomSanitizer} from '@angular/platform-browser';
   @Pipe({name: 'safeHtml'})
   export class SafeHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform {
   constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer){}

    transform(html: string) {
       return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(html);
    }
  }
  ```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem is that i'm not executing this code in the app component but inside a function that is called afterViewInit. I don't think your solution fits this case.

Comment: I see. best solution would be Dynamic Components in your case.  check https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

Answer (score 0):

Can try to make html trusted code directly, without create a pipe.
add an imnport

```
import { DomSanitizer } from "@angular/platform-browser";
```

inject the service in constructor

```
  constructor(
  ...,
    private sanitizer: DomSanitizer,
   ...
  ) { }
```

use it when set the innerHTML of element (rewrite the line of your code)

```
list!.innerHTML += this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(thingExp);
```